# Check existence of a relation in a model

Tags: yii, yii-extensions, yii-components

I have a parent model *ParentModel*, and in it I want to check if *ChildModel* has a relation, say, *user* or not.

I try something like:

```
$relation = "user";
if (isset($this->$relation)){
//    dosomething
}
```

but the condition is always false even when the relation actually exists.

I know it is a naive question.... :( okay, sue me, I can't find the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> ```
>   $relation = "user";
>   if (!empty($this->$relation)){
>    //    dosomething
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I find an answer

```
isset($this->relations()[$relation])
```